# How to launch apps from existing project in MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How do I do the following tasks:

I have main app that will launch different apps.

1. what is required for this task.
2. How to pass data to/from Launched-app and main app.
3. How to debug for this ?

Thanks

Comment: This works no different then any other Android / Xamarin code in MvvmCross. You should start an `Intent` and add some data to it with the methods it has available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how this is done in the WebBrowser, SMS, Email and Phone plugins. As @martjin00 mentioned in the comments you use something called an `Intent` to launch an `Activity`. Whether it is your own or someone else's `Activity` does not matter.

An `Intent` allows the developer to put in extra arguments. However, they obviously need to be of a format the target `Activity` understands when it receives the `Intent`. If you know this (you obviously should if you are launching your own apps), then it is fairly trivial to do this.

The mentioned plugins do exactly that. They call default apps with a defined set of arguments that can be passed to the `Intent`. The plugins just expose this so it can be triggered from a PCL and would potentially work on multiple platforms if you implement your own stuff for each platform.

So lets say we have `Activity` **A** which is the target `Activity` you want to launch. It takes some piece of data as argument:

```
public class A : Activity
{
    protected override OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var animal = Intent.GetStringExtra ("animal");
    }
}
```

Then the source `Activity` **B** now wants to start **A** giving it an animal, lets say *horse*.

```
var intent = new Intent (typeof(A));
intent.PutExtra ("animal", "horse");
StartActivity (intent);
```

That is basically it. If **A** is not contained in your own app but is in an external app, the `Intent` would be a bit different:

```
var intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage ("some.other.App");
intent.PutExtra ("animal", "horse");
StartActivity (intent);
```